# Round Decimal Numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve below round decimal numbers in javascript :

```
Before  | After
10.05   | 10.05  
10.04   | 10.00
10.02   | 10.00
10.07   | 10.10
```

As I made a research on google and stackoverflow, I am able to do this:

```
number = Math.round(number* 20) / 20;
number = parseFloat(number).toFixed(2);
```

but the result will be:

```
Before  | After
10.05   | 10.05  
10.04   | 10.00
10.07   | 10.05 // supposed to be 10.10 if decimal is > 0.5
```

May I know how to achieve this?

Comment: you want 10.04 to round DOWN, but 10.07 to round UP ... that's some freaky math you'll need ... and your code will round 10.04 to 10.05, not 10.00

Comment: Not really, can't you just use `Math.ceil` instead of `round`?

Comment: `Math.ceil(10.07* 20) / 20 === 10.1`

Comment: Math.ceil would also cause 10.04 to become 10.05

Comment: Ah yeah, hadn't noticed. I retract my comment.

Comment: the problem is the misunderstanding of rounding and that you can't randomly round up or down according to whim

Comment: The result is mathematically correct, because 10.07 is closer to 10.05 (differ 0.02) than to 10.10 (differ 0.03). If you want to achieve what you told, there should be `if`s.

Comment: thanks for the info guys. @BornToCode, let say if I want to use `if`, what is the condition for me to insert if the number is an input given by user? for example `if(number > 0.05) : will multiply by 10`. Is it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Multiply the number by 10 and round that:</strike>

```
number = Math.round(number * 10) / 10;
number.toFixed(2);
```

Or in one line:

```
number = (Math.round(number * 10) / 10).toFixed(2);
```

The following snippet shows this in action:

```js
var numbers = [10.05, 10.04, 10.02, 10.07];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    console.log(numbers[i] + ' -> ' + (Math.round(numbers[i] * 10) / 10).toFixed(2));
}
```

**EDIT:** Preserving the *.05 can be done with an `if` statement like so:

```
number = number * 10;
number = number % 0.5 === 0 ? number : Math.round(number);
number = number / 10;
number.toFixed(2);
```

```js
var numbers = [10.05, 10.04, 10.02, 10.07];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var number = numbers[i] * 10;
    number = number % 0.5 === 0 ? number : Math.round(number);
    number = number / 10;
    console.log(numbers[i] + ' -> ' + number.toFixed(2));
}
```

**EXPLANATION:**

**What does `number = number % 0.5 === 0 ? number : Math.round(number);` do?**

I'll break it down. The above code uses a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to assign a value to `number`. (Ternary expressions are of the form `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false;`.)

The condition in this case is `number % 0.5 === 0`. This uses the [remainder operator (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) to see if number is divisible by `0.5`. (The remainder of `number / 0.5` is `0` if the number is divisible by `0.5`.)

Thus the full ternary can be translated as:

> If the number is divisible by `0.5`, take `number`, otherwise take `Math.round(number)`. Then, assign the taken value back to `number`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SumnerEvans but I want the number to remain the same if the decimal is 0.05. Example, `10.05 -> 10.05`

Comment: Ok. From a pure mathematical definition of rounding, if you are wanting to round to the nearest 0.05, then 10.03, 10.04, 10.06 and 10.07 should also round to 10.05. Could you please clarify what you are trying to round to? It appears that you are trying to round to the nearest 0.1 unless it is *.05 in which case don't round at all.

Comment: **Thank you very much for the help!** May you explain this line `number = number % 0.5 == 0 ? number : Math.round(number);`. What does it check?

Comment: @Amran I have updated my answer with an explanation of that line.

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(10.07 * 20) / 20);
```

Of course keeping in mind `10.04` will round *down* to `10.1` and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
var number = Math.round(10.05*10)/10; //this basically does the trick
var number = number.toFixed(2);
console.log(number);
```